# "Debugging is being stopped" but is not yet complete

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

All of a sudden, my Visual Studio has begun to popup a message every time I want to break my ASP.net project.

[image: "Debugging is being stopped but is not yet complete" dialog message.]

How can I get rid of this dialog?

There is nothing to complete, only a debug session to get rid of. Clicking the "Stop Now" button will not immediately stop the execution, but wait some seconds.

From what I know, I have not changed any configuration to get this dialog.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1072406.aspx?Stop+Debugging+Command+Doesn+t+Stop+Execution

Comment: FYI:this seems to be fixed in visual studio 2017:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/33482/asp-net-core-debugging-closing-browser-window-does.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting all breakpoints **(Menu > Debug > Delete All Breakpoints)** and running in Debug mode fixed it. Unfortunately, nothing else did it for me. I had to again set the breakpoints that I wanted.

Alternatively, you can choose to work around this problem by choosing the **Menu > Debug > Terminate All** option instead of clicking the **Stop Debugging (Shift + F5)** button.

Microsoft announced that they have fixed it in the new release of VS 2017, per this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/33482/asp-net-core-debugging-closing-browser-window-does.html):

Comment: Aaand it's broken again.

Comment: Yes, it keeps showing itself once in a while for me too, after the update. However, its far less than how it was before. I haven't been able to get hold of a permanent solution yet.

Comment: Still broke for me in VS 2019 and its now September 2020. I'm on 16.4.5

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting my log files and this fixed the issue for me. I think it stalled while trying to write when the files got so large, somehow.

Inside the project folder, try deleting all the log files in `\bin\Debug\logs` (path my vary depending on your own config)